# Assign values to disconnected recordset - SQL Server 2008 vs 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I update the value of a column on a discconected recordset using SQL Server 2008?

The following Delphi code (xe5) works on SQL Server 2008r2 but not on SQL Server 2008.  It returns a multi-step exception when using 2008.  The only non-zero return code for this statement is -2147217887.  A search on that error code returned no results.

```
 rsResult.Fields['Group_No'].Value := iGroup;

rsResult is a disconnected recordset opened with 
Open(Query, Connection.ConnectionObject, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, Integer(adOptionUnspecified));
```

The recordset will never be updated to the database, I only use the new values on the client side.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I am not a Delphi developer, but if you aren't going to update the database with that record, could you use some other data structure than a recordset?

Comment: @AnnL. Thanks for the suggestion.  Yes I could however it would mean a significant rework of existing logic that is all based on recordset.

Comment: Again, not a Delphi developer, but does the recordset need to be opened as a SQL Server recordset?  Could it be some other kind of recordset?